# Antlr4 StringTemplate not compatible with Json.net dynamic items

Tags: json, dynamic, json.net, stringtemplate

I would like to read a dynamic object from a json file and then use this in a stringTemplate.

The following code works.

```
dynamic data = new { bcName = "Lixam B.V", periodName = "July 2013" };
var engine = new Template("<m.bcName> <m.periodName>");
engine.Add("m", data);
engine.Render().Should().Be("Lixam B.V July 2013");
```

The following code fails

```
var json = "{bcName : 'Lixam B.V', periodName : 'July 2013'}";
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
string name = (data.bcName);
name.Should().Be("Lixam B.V"); // this passes
var engine = new Template("<m.bcName> <m.periodName>");
engine.Add("m", data);
engine.Render().Should().Be("Lixam B.V July 2013"); //fails
```

Is there another way to configure JsonConverter to be compatible with StringTemplate

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `IModelAdaptor` for whatever the compiled type representing `dynamic` is, and register it using `TemplateGroup.RegisterModelAdaptor`.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired on [Mr. Harwell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076965/antlr4-stringtemplate-not-compatible-with-json-net-dynamic-items#answer-23082198), I've implemented an `IModelAdaptor` that enable the usage of Newtonsoft.Json parsed objects.

Here it goes:

```
internal class JTokenModelAdaptor : Antlr4.StringTemplate.IModelAdaptor
{
    public object GetProperty(
        Antlr4.StringTemplate.Interpreter interpreter,
        Antlr4.StringTemplate.TemplateFrame frame,
        object obj,
        object property,
        string propertyName)
    {
        var token = (obj as JToken)?.SelectToken(propertyName);
        if (token == null)
            return null;
        if (token is JValue)
        {
            var jval = token as JValue;
            return jval.Value;
        }
        return token;
    }
}
```

You just need to register the adaptor in your template group, like this:

```
template.Group.RegisterModelAdaptor(typeof(JToken), new JTokenModelAdaptor());
```